# SHAREPOINT -Restrict duplicate Entry

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Guys Required support for below scenario
i have one list for booking with date and time . i want to restrict the duplicate entry by date and time
i have tried the rest Api code but it's not working.. please support find below my code

i tried to check with one condition .. i need to check with two conditions

Please support

```js
<script src="/Departments/WDCI/UIJP/PublishingImages/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">
        function PreSaveAction() {
            var check = false;
            var listid = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
            var DateId = $('input[id*="Date_Req"]');
            
            $.ajax({
                //replace the rest api to filter items based on your files
   url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'" + listid + "')/items?$select=ID,Req_Date,Req_Time,Title&$orderby=ID desc&$filter=Date_Req eq  + DateId + ",
                                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var count = data.d.results.length;
                    if (count < 2) {
                        check = true;
                    } else {
                        alert('Dear Employee,This Calander Year you have already applied for two Job Positions.So you are eligible to apply next year only');
                     ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={/SiteAssets/Thank%20You.aspx}')
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            })
        
                           return check;
        }
</script>
```

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript">
</script><script type="text/javascript">
        function PreSaveAction() {
            var check = false;
            var listid = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
            var DateId = $('input[id*="Date_Req"]');
            
            $.ajax({
                //replace the rest api to filter items based on your files
   url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'" + listid + "')/items?$select=ID,Req_Date,Req_Time,Title&$orderby=ID desc&$filter=Date_Req eq  + DateId + ",
                                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var count = data.d.results.length;
                    if (count < 1) {
                        check = true;
                    } else {
                        alert('Dear Employee,there is no slot available during this period');
                     ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={/SiteAssets/Thank%20You.aspx}')
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            })
        
                           return check;
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
<script type="text/javascript">
       function PreSaveAction() {
           var check = false;
           //var listid = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
           var DateId = $("input[Title*='Req_Date']").val();
           var TimeID= $("select[Title*='Req_Time'] option:selected").text();


           alert(DateId);
           alert(TimeID);
           $.ajax({
 //replace the rest api to filter items based on your files 
 url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists//GetByTitle('Discussion2')/items?$select=ID,Req_Date,Req_Time,Title&$orderby=ID desc&$filter= Req_Date eq '" + DateId + "' and Req_Time eq '" + TimeID + "'",                type: 'GET',
               async: false,
               headers: {
                   "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                   "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
               },
               success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                   var count = data.d.results.length;
                   if (count < 1) {
                       check = true;
                   } else {
                       alert('Dear Employee,there is no slot available during this period');
                   }
               },
               error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   alert(textStatus);
               }
           })
       
                          return check;
       }
</script>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to restrict duplicate entry:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function PreSaveAction() {
            var check = false;
            //var listid = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
            var DateId = $("input[title='Date_Req']").val();
            alert(DateId);
            $.ajax({
                //replace the rest api to filter items based on your files
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists//GetByTitle('List0325')/items?$select=ID,Date_Req,Title&$orderby=ID desc&$filter=Date_Req eq '"  + DateId + "'",
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var count = data.d.results.length;
                    if (count < 1) {
                        check = true;
                    } else {
                        alert('Dear Employee,there is no slot available during this period');
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            })
        
                           return check;
        }
</script>
```

Note: you need to change the followings:

1. In `var DateId = $("input[title='Date_Req']").val()`, change "Date_Req" to your date column name;
2. In $.ajax(), change List title and columns' names to yours in **url** part

The result is like:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the suppot..still no luck. seems value is not fetching from column to variable

Comment: In my code, I added alert(DateId); to alert the column value, you can also do that. Also, you can use F12 to debug your code to see if anything is wrong.

Comment: Thank Dear Kally.. now it's working .. there was some issue with variable name .. it's corrected .. One more thing to filter multiple query for Ex below code is correct ? i tried but not getting result //url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists//GetByTitle('Discussion2')/items?$select=ID,Req_Date,Req_Time,Title&$orderby=ID desc&$filter=Req_Date eq '"  + DateId + "' and Req_Time eq '"+TimeID "'", can u please have a look n suggest. Thanks

Comment: thank you Dear Kally.. it's resolved..Thanks Everyone